# Unexpected GET request after POST on AJAX call to MVC Action

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, http, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an action method that is invoked with POST method over AJAX. Method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(MyModel model)
{
    /// do something and save
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

What happens is that after this method is call by the $.ajax, from unknown reason follow up GET request is made to same controller and same action. This call is not made anywhere and it's probably implemented either in browser or in ASP.NET MVC as Post/Redirect/Get pattern which I don't need in this case.

Is there a way to disable this programmatically because GET counterpart of Save method is not implemented and server returns 404 with HTML contents in it.

EDIT, this is the client-side AJAX script:

```
function saveDonkey(donkey) {
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(donkey);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Donkey/Save",
        data: jsonData,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function () {
            fetchPage(); /// This just issues GET request to another predefined method
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you post some of the client side script, all looks ok with the server side, maybe you are not preventing the default GET behavior if you are using a link or form, but im just guessing at this point.

Comment: My guess would be you're submitting a form to send the `$.ajax` and not stopping the standard form submission with `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: So you're saying that when I use $.ajax with POST I should call e.preventDefault() on success?

Comment: @BarisaPuter depends on what event you are handling to call $.ajax.  What calls your `saveDonkey` method?

Comment: None really, it's just method that does some jQuery parsing to create donkey object, and then does saveDonkey(donkey) which is really just a shorthand to $.ajax call.

Comment: I have a feeling HttpStatusCodeResult might be doing this but I can't find how and why...

Comment: Nothing calls your `saveDonkey` method?  How can that be?

Comment: No, the method that calls it is just some method that is invoked on document.ready event. It reads up some values from the document, forms the object donkey by using $ selectors and calls saveDonkey(donkey). So for this issue it is not relevant.

Comment: Well there must be something else making that request, assuming `fetchPage()` is not doing it.